# Any one can explain how to use library project in Android (eclipse)?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity, android-library, library-project

I am new for android. Here i try to create an library project to set image in image view when call the method call(). Code like in libProject

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.imagelayout);
}
public void call(){ ...........}
```

I create an android library project name as libProject in eclipse with the above code in the way of Project->R-click->properties->Android->check Is Library.
and then i create an new android app project name as demotest for testing purpose
in here i copy the libProject.jar file in bin folder and paste in to demotest libs folder and the libScreen.xml into demotest layout. And then i import header file like`import com.name.libProject.Image;` and then i create an object for Image class and i call an method of that libProject like 

`Image imgsam = new Image();
imgsam.call();` .Then i run it but it say **app** **unfortunately has stopped**. If anyone know the answer.